# How to keep track of image licenses sold?

Tags: business, licensing, selling

When selling licenses to images, how to keep track who has bought what rights to what images? Accounting seems to kind of track this information, but it still needs some way to to connect images to accounting records about it.

Are there any standard solutions or does every photographer build one's own system? What solution do you use, or does this info not matter at all?

Comment: Have a look at [DigiMarc](http://www.digimarc.com/digimarc-for-images)

Comment: It's a watermarking service letting me search where my images are used; my question is about keeping track who has bought licenses, which this service does not seem to cover. When Digimarc finds a usage of my image, how will I know if it's been paid for?

Comment: Digimarc does have an mobile application and a search engine service that will tell you where your image is being used. If I remember correctly, they embed an unique id into your image that is invisible. (Theoretically,) If you compare the results of that search engine with your sales entries you should get fairly good idea of who is not paying for your work.

Comment: Thank you for your input, but my question is more about that other half - a system for keeping the "sales entries", not a system for tracking image usage.

Answer (score 1):

I think some pros buy a digital asset management system (try doing a web search for something like "photography digital asset management system").   I've never used one.